# Creating a thumbnail card with buttons in Bot Framework for Node.js without the session object

Tags: node.js, botframework

My bot has a timer job that checks for something every N minutes and sends a reminder to the user.

Since this is a timer job, that means it's outside any dialog and I don't have access to the `session` object.

The code works fine if I create the reminder message like this:

```
new builder.Message().text("This is a reminder!");
```

However, this code does not work because the `CardAction` requires a `session` object as a parameter:

```
var card = new builder.ThumbnailCard()
    .title("Reminder")
    .text("Hey it's a reminder.")
    .images([exclamation_mark_image_url])
    .buttons([builder.CardAction.imBack(null, "check", "Check Overdue")]); //should use `session` instead of null here
```

The error is a 500 Internal Server Error response from the botframework.com server in chat connector.

This is how I send the generate message when the `session` object is not available:

```
//`msg` is the message with a card generated in the code above
bot.beginDialog(address, dialog_name, msg, function (err) {
    //nothing
});
```

How can I create a ThumbnailCard with a button without a `session` object?

Comment: Make a function that does your XYZ task, and pass in the session object as an argument. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is store the address of the user, and then use `bot.loadSession(storedAddress, function (err, session) {});` This will generate the session object based on the passed in address. In its callback you can use the session object to send messages. I've used the method on a webhook to alert users when certain events are occurring.

Depending on how you're storing the timer/alarm, you can also store the user's last `session.message.address` with that data. I haven't worked on the implementation of such a bot, but the next part would be adding a job/method that checks a list of alarms continuously/periodically and then sends the message to the user when their alarm is triggered.

Comment: Excellent, `loadSession()` is exactly the function I needed. Thanks.