# How to invoke Microsoft Bot periodically

Tags: botframework

Can a Microsoft Bot send some message periodically(after a fixed duration of time) to me in Bot Emulator or Microsoft Teams without explicitly tagging it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to schedule tasks in Microsoft Bot Framework + C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38431234/how-to-schedule-tasks-in-microsoft-bot-framework-c)

Comment: You can create your own third party service.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you've interacted with the bot beforehand (and it has your address stored (e.g. [session.message.address](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/interfaces/_botbuilder_d_.imessage.html#address) in Node) you can do what you're asking for. To search for more info you'll want to look up questions/issues on sending *"proactive messages"*.

You can see question [44757727](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44757727/creating-a-thumbnail-card-with-buttons-in-bot-framework-for-node-js-without-the/44769220#44769220) to find more a little more talk on the concept. If you check out MicrosoftDX's repo ["botFramework-proactiveMessages"](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/botFramework-proactiveMessages) you can find examples for both Node and .NET.